# DIV desalinhando quando inserido texto dentro

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou fazendo alguns quadros com a ajuda de CSS Triangle para chegar no ponto que preciso. Porém quando insiro o texto dentro do BOX, ele está desalinhando. O Meu intuito é que o texto fique alinhando dentro do BOX conforme [print](http://prntscr.com/ardoi0).

Segue o [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jotkf2jn/).

Comment: Mas já está assim.. eu fiz uma div normal, e coloquei um :before pra fazer o elemento do triangulo para simular um corte. Mas quando eu insiro o texto dento da div, ele quebra com esse :before. Dá uma olhada no fiddle que coloquei...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta colocar o < p> em position:absolute.

Exemplo.:
https://jsfiddle.net/jotkf2jn/1/

Coloquei top e left só para não ficar em cima da curva.
Não consegui abrir a imagem para ver o que seria o pretendido.

Comment: aqui abriu certo o print... estranho

Comment: funcionou certinho... obrigado!